# How to get timing information in google speech to text Python API client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api-client

According to https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/speech/syncrecognize#SpeechRecognitionAlternative output object has only the following:

```
{
 "transcript": string,
 "confidence": number,
}
```

How to get the timing information of the transcript here?

Below is the code snippet:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech

ip = sys.argv[1]
op = sys.argv[2]
# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

operation = client.long_running_recognize(
    audio=speech.types.RecognitionAudio(
        uri='gs://my-bucket/' + ip,
    ),
    config=speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US',
        model='default',#model='video',
    ),
)
```

I want to create a subtitle file from its output, so timing information is crutial.

More details: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python